In Android emulator in the extended control section Google Maps is not showing, only an empty screen appears. How to fix?
I have an Android emulator with the below specified configuration. The issue what is happening is whenever I try to open the extended controls in the location tab the map is not showing, instead it's showing an empty screen with the search box for both the single points and route. I need the routes to test my delivery app. I am in trouble currently. Also the thing to highlight is whatever I type in the location search box, it returns nothing. I need it to solve to proceed for further development.
android studio version: 2024.1.1.
Emulator: pixel 8 pro api 35
sdk:    android sdk platform 35 35  1   Installed
    sources for android 35  35  1   Installed
    google apis arm54 v8a system image  35  6   Installed
    google apis intel x86-64 atom system image  35  6   Installed
    google play arm54 v8a system image  35  6   Installed
    google apis intel x86-64 atom system image  35  6   Installed
sdk build tools:
Android sdk build tools 35:
35.0.0
sdk cmdlines tool: 
Android sdk cmdlines tools(latest) version 13.0 installed.

Android sdk platform tools:
version 35.0.1

I have tried to update Android Studio, and to update the SDK and all. I have tried by clearing the ADV folder, the cold boot method, nothing works for me. By trying the solution I am currently at latest in every aspect. But nothing helps. I have tried available Stack Overflow solution and the Google default documentation to solve it. Now I want it to be solved. It's currently beyond my understanding.

Are you able to provide a repository that we can check?
